# SignalR : typeof jQuery.connection.chatHub is "undefined" after page refresh in webkit & moz

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

Why do i get undefined for value of `jQuery.connection.chatHub` when I refresh page? This problem does not appear in IE and Edge

**Server Side:**

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
[Authorize]
    public class ChatHub:IHub<IHubClient>{
.....
}
```

Client Side

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var k = jQuery.connection.chatHub;
alert(typeof k);
}
.......
//Laiter
.....
jQuery.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'], xdomain: true }).done(function () {
                        "uid-0" && (k.server.onconnect(JSON.stringify("'uid':'Test User'}")));
 })
</script>
```

The first page load work well but subsequent attempts to reload fail with this error.

Libraries used:

- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.0"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="2.1.2"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.0"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Hubs.js file that's specified by your 
 element
This needs to point to where it is generated by your ChatHub class in the background

Comment: Its already defined. By the way this happens when the page is refreshed.